# Installing and using super-filter plugin

Tags: plugin-superfilter

I'm currently testing the [super-filter](https://github.com/pdaleramirez/super-filter/blob/master/README.md) and I was wondering if someone has experience working with this plugin. The instructions are unfortunately very unclear to me. I've come as far as trying to create a new search setup but I'm dumbfounded by the following

[image]

What exactly do I have to put here and what does it do?

The documentation offers the following, but it doesn't make sense to me: "Template Override Folder - the folder of the templates that you'll override to modify html's. The items.twig must be copied to this folder to modify element attributes."

I am also unclear where to put the following code mentioned in the documentation.

```
    {{ craft.superFilter.setup('searchList') }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
            {{ craft.superFilter.displaySearchFields() }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">
            {{ craft.superFilter.displaySortOptions() }}
            {{ craft.superFilter.items() }}
            {{ craft.superFilter.getPaginateLinks() }}
            {{ craft.superFilter.close() }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

This is an option to modify the html element that is being used by the search field. You will have to specify the folder in your site template path what template file to override. You can start by copying and pasting sample html template in vendor/pdaleramirez/super-filter/templates to the specified template override folder.